# get internet message id of conversation (not ConversationTopic)

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

We can get internet message id of outlook using property accessor.

How can we get internet message id of its conversation (equivalent to references item in header string).

Details:
I agree that we can get conversationtopic but most of my data/code uses references part in header string(fetched from header string) to detemine if it belongs to conversation.

And some emails (like sent mails in exchange) wont have header string, so to determine the thread it belongs to, I need internet message id of its conversation(should be able to generate without header string, like using property accessor or some dot property).

Also, is there any page that shows list of all mapi properties.

Also, I dont mean  message_id of conversation, but I am expecting message_id of first message in conversation(equivalent of references in header string).  Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Conversation does not have a message id since multiple messages can belong to the same conversation.
You can read `PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX` property and extract the parent conversation index from it - see [Tracking Conversations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc765583(v=office.15).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I actually need message_id of first message in conv, equivalent to references in normal headers. Can i get them? Or atleast message_id of parent email ?

Comment: The best you can do is take the first 22 bytes of PR_CONVERSATION_INDEX and search for a match in the Inbox or Sent Items folder. Keep in mind that OOM won't let you search ion binary properties, you will need to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (any language) for tat.